# Unable to connect to server using filezilla

Tags: filezilla

```
Command:    PWD
Response:   534 Fallback to [C]
Error:      Failed to retrieve directory listing
Response:   257 "/" is your current location
```

This is the error I am getting how to resolve it. Do I need to change any system settings. If I have, please let me know .

Answer (score 1):

```
Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

This is telling me a few things.

- Either you don't have read access (also check SELinux for access to homedirs -- `setsebool -P ftp_home_dir=1` will allow users to read their home directories)
- Or you are in active mode and possibly a firewall is in your way.

Try switching to passive mode and try again. I'd also contact the server administrator if you can, they would know where you're going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like SSL/TLS issue, some servers who support SSL/TLS do not allow users to transfer encrypted data. (like LIST,RETR,STOR) and only secure command channel is allowed.

try using a non encrypted method.

if this fails, it may be a server firewall issue (but it doesn't seem to be the issue here as I guess there are more people connecting.)